# Android : String [] array, iterate and match answers stored in a String []

Tags: android, arrays

The user of the app submits a String array. I want to match the array against a list of predefined id's. And store it in a new array. Anyone have a clue how to do this :)?

The ID's have to be predefined. And need to match the correct "String array name". 
Like in the example, if the user chose 1, the output in the final String array have to be id_1.  So I need to check the user choices against the ID array, to determine what was selected, after this I need to translate the original choices into the correct id's.

**Like this :**

```
//User chose these items from a listview.
String [] choices = { "1","2","3" };

// Predefined values.
String id_1 = "1";
String id_2 = "2";
String id_3 = "3";

//Sorts out, and switches the choices with the id.
Some code to do this; 

String [] sorted_choices = {"id_1","id_2", "id_3"};
```

Comment: what is your question? what have you tried?

Comment: What are these id's? Are they string resources from an XML file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `match the array against a list of predefined id's. And store it in a new array`? To me, that could mean anything, like "see if the user input matches an array I already have elsewhere" to "use the user input to make an array of IDs."

Comment: The whole idea is based on this. I have a Huge string array containing options for the user. For each option the user choses (in a multiple choice listview, I have to translate the choices into an ID. The ID is actually a category number matching the choice the user made from the listview. In the end I want to take all the ID's and make a URL out it for the WebView.

So if the user chooses "Example 1" from the ListView, I have to translate this into and ID (already set in a XML file or another string) In the end i would feed the WebView with a www.url.com/45 (If the id of example 1 is 45.

Answer (score 1):

If the items in the ListView are in the same order as their id's, you can use [getCheckedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition%28%29) to retrieve the value of the id. (You may need to add 1. The docs do not state if the returned value starts at 0 or 1.)

If this is not possible, then you will need to use some data structure to associate the id with the item in the ListView. It sounds like a `Map` might be the right tool for your situation.

Comment: Thanks, that may be the answer. But how would i implement the getCheckedItemsPosition() if the user picks several items from the list?

Comment: @iNzzane I strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with the [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/index.html). The link I gave jumps directly to the docs for the `getCheckedItemPosition()` for the `AbsListView` class. On that same web page, you can read about all the other methods available in this class. One of those will do exactly what you want.